# NASM and gdbgui

Tags: gdb, nasm

Could someone give the cue can I use gdbgui for NASM. If yes what I should do for that? I use command nasm -felf64 -g -Fdwarf. But when I launch gdbgui I face this message: "No symbol table is loaded.Use the "file" command."

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63744918/debug-symbols-in-nasm-once-more